# chart.js change size of label of radar chart

Tags: charts, label, chart.js

I use Chart.js to create a radar chart. I would like change the size of label but i don't find the option.ind my code here :

```js
var data = {
 labels:  ajax_label,
    pointLabelFontSize : 16,
    scaleFontSize: 16,
    datasets: [
    {
       label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(91, 192, 222,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(91, 192, 222,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(91, 192, 222,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(91, 192, 222,1)",
    data: ajax_data,
    scaleShowLabels : false,
    scaleOverride: true,

// ** Required if scaleOverride is true **
    // Number - The number of steps in a hard coded scale
    scaleSteps: 10,
    // Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
    scaleStepWidth: 10,
    // Number - The scale starting value
    scaleStartValue: 0
    }
    ]
    };

var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
new Chart(ctx).Radar(data, {
pointDot: false
});
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Radar chart has some chart-specific options that can be rolled in the the global chart options.  One of these options is `pointLabelFontSize` which takes a number value.  This option needs to be set in the same place you're currently setting the `pointDot` value in order to take effect:

```
new Chart(ctx).Radar(data, {
    pointDot: false,
    pointLabelFontSize: 20
});
```

Note: the value for `pointLabelFontSize` is in pixels